# Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm using `IndexDB` to create an object store of users but when trying to add users I get an error on the `var request = db.transaction(['person'], 'readwrite')` line.

The error given is:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of 
>    undefined
>       at add (test.js:32)
>       at test.js:45"

My script looks like this:

```
var request = window.indexedDB.open("connectDB", 1);

request.onerror = function (event) 
{
console.log('The database is opened failed');
};

var db;

request.onsuccess = function (event) 
{
    db = request.result;
console.log('The database is opened successfully');
};

var db;

request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) 
{
    db = event.target.result;
    var objectStore;
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('users'))
    {
        objectStore = db.createObjectStore('users', { keyPath: 'id' });
        objectStore.createIndex('name', 'name', { unique: false });
        objectStore.createIndex('email', 'email', { unique: true });
    }
}

function add() 
{
  var request = db.transaction(['person'], 'readwrite')
    .objectStore('person')
    .add({ id: 1, name: 'Jam', age: 24, email: 'jam@example.com' });

  request.onsuccess = function (event) {
    console.log('The data has been written successfully');
  };

  request.onerror = function (event) {
    console.log('The data has been written failed');
  }
}

add();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to access `db` during the call to `add()` when it is uninitialized (note that this call to `add()` occurs immediatly when your script is executed).

The `db` variable is however only initialized if the database connection is successfully created:

```
request.onsuccess = function (event) 
{
    db = request.result;
    console.log('The database is opened successfully');

    // It is now safe to interact with the database
};
```

There are number of ways this problem can be addressed though the simplest would be to move your call to `add()` into the `onsuccess` handler like so:

```
request.onsuccess = function (event) 
{
    db = request.result;
    console.log('The database is opened successfully');

    add(); // Add this
};

// add(); <-- remove this from the end of your script
```

Finally, I noticed you have two `var db;` variables declared - consider removing one of those. Hope this helps!

Comment: this seems to reduce flexibility. what if I want to use db where ever I want to?